# Controlling where an opened window appears

Tags: unity-2d

I often find myself opening emacs from the terminal in order to copy down something from the internet. Regretfully, the thing I am usually attempting to copy down is in the upper left-hand portion of the screen - precisely where the emacs window opens.

How might change things so that emacs opens in the upper right-hand portion of the screen?

I'm using unity-2d so Compiz cannot be used. Any other way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

Install compizconfig-settings-manager.

From ccsm go to the place windows plugin.

You can either choose to have windows open in the centre of the screen (use placement mode in the general tab),

[image]

or you can have them open in specific positions by using the fixed placement tab:

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm using unity-2d where compiz isn't an option. Alternative methods?

Comment: @sywisy: I'll have to look that up. You should have mentioned that in your original question (which you didn't) :).